# Android: Turning off text darkening while scrolling

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to explicitly turn off the darkening of text during scrolling?

In this case I have set up the text view as follows:

```
public class DebugActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        TextView error_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
        error_textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        error_textview.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("content"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simply works for me

Simply add `android:textColor="#ffffff"` inside your `TextView` tag in your xml file.

This may be a quick fix for you. But this works fine.